# Проверка соединения клиента с сервером

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Подскажите, как сервер работающий на [WebSocket](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) может проверить есть ли соединение с клиентом ?

Answer (score 0):

Отправь ping https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/server.html#websockets.server.WebSocketServerProtocol.ping

Который можно настроить чтоб отсылался в фоне постоянно. Но если прямо в определенный момент, то именно так будет правильно и надёжно.